# Reading file string into an array (In a pythonic way)

Tags: python, arrays, file-io, floating-point

I'm reading lines from a file to then work with them. Each line is composed solely by float numbers.

I have pretty much everything sorted up to convert the lines into arrays.

I basically do (pseudopython code)

```
 line=file.readlines()
 line=line.split(' ') # Or whatever separator
 array=np.array(line)
 #And then iterate over every value casting them as floats
      newarray[i]=array.float(array[i])
```

This works, buts seems a bit counterintuitive and antipythonic, I wanted to know if there is a better way to handle the inputs from a file to have at the end an array full of floats.

Comment: Please fix your pseudo-code.  If you have a `for` statement, please actually write the `for` statement, rather than a comment.  Are you asking for `newarray=[ float(x) for x in array ]` or `newarray = map( float, array )`?  It's not clear what you're looking for.

Comment: @S.Lott The couple of answers I got implemented exactly what I asked for :). I did not write the for, because it could be a do, a for, or any other kind of loop instruction, I just wanted to point I was iterating over the variables. I basically want an array full of floats that are in a text file.

Comment: @Leon palafox: If I enter "executable pseudocode" into a search engine, the first hit I get is for Python. We don't need pseudopython.

Comment: @Johnsyweb And 10 years ago you probably got a Java Pseudo code, I rather be explicit in my terminology rather than hope python will keep being this popular ;)

Comment: @Leon palafox: Psedo-Python is made-up nonsense.  It is not *explicit*.  It's junk.  "rather than hope python will keep being this popular" is exactly backwards.  Millions of programmers know Python.  No one knows the made-up pseudo-python except you.  Please don't use made-up pseudo-junk when you could (with very little change) written simple, clear, well-known, obvious-to-many Python.

Comment: Sorry, no time to discuss HOW I put my question rather than my question itself. I guess that if you have a problem on how I asked, you could always make no comment ;).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick answer:

```
arrays = []
for line in open(your_file): # no need to use readlines if you don't want to store them
    # use a list comprehension to build your array on the fly
    new_array = np.array((array.float(i) for i in line.split(' '))) 
    arrays.append(new_array)
```

If you process often this kind of data, the csv module will help.

```
import csv

arrays = []
# declare the format of you csv file and Python will turn line into
# lists for you 
parser = csv.reader(open(your_file), delimiter=' '))
for l in parser: 
    arrays.append(np.array((array.float(i) for i in l)))
```

If you feel wild, you can even make this completly declarative:

```
import csv

parser = csv.reader(open(your_file), delimiter=' '))
make_array = lambda row : np.array((array.float(i) for i in row)) 
arrays = [make_array(row) for row in parser]
```

And if you realy want you colleagues to hate you, you can make a one liner (NOT PYTHONIC AT ALL :-):

```
arrays = [np.array((array.float(i) for i in r)) for r in csv.reader(open(your_file), delimiter=' '))]
```

Stripping all the boiler plate and flexibility, you can end up with a clean and quite readable one liner. I wouldn't use it because I like the refatoring potential of using `csv`, but it can be good enought. It's a grey zone here, so I wouldn't say it's Pythonic, but it's definitly handy.

```
arrays = [np.array((array.float(i) for i in l.split())) for l in open(your_file))]
```

Answer (score 7):

[If you want a numpy array and each row in the text file has the same number of values](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt):

```
a = numpy.loadtxt('data.txt')
```

Without numpy:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    arrays = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC))
```

[Or just](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11052880/4279):

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    arrays = [map(float, line.split()) for line in f]
```

Comment: `numpy.loadtxt()` is the right way to do it, if numpy can be used. +1

Comment: the last solution that includes `map` is so simple and works!

Answer (score 3):

How about the following:

```
import numpy as np

arrays = []
for line in open('data.txt'):
  arrays.append(np.array([float(val) for val in line.rstrip('\n').split(' ') if val != '']))
```

Comment: Make this even more useful by making it as a function,def f(type=float) and then use type(val) in the list comprehension.

Comment: Don't use the name `type`, it's reserved. `def f(typ=float)` or `def f(tipe=float)` would be better.

Answer (score 1):

One possible one-liner:

```
a_list = [map(float, line.split(' ')) for line in a_file]
```

Note that I used `map()` here instead of a nested list comprehension to aid readability.

If you want a numpy array:

```
an_array = np.array([map(float, line.split(' ')) for line in a_file])
```

Comment: you can omit `' '` argument for `.split()`

Comment: Sure you can, but I prefer making things explicit when answering SO questions. In my own code, which is largely read by people familiar with Python, or at least programming, I tend to leave it out.

Answer (score 0):

I would use regular expressions

import re

```
all_lines = ''.join( file.readlines() )

new_array = np.array( re.findall('[\d.E+-]+', all_lines), float)

np.reshape( new_array, (m,n) )
```

First merging the files into one long string, and then extracting only the expressions corresponding to floats ( **'[\d.E+-]'** for scientific notation, but you can also use **'[\d.]'** for only float expressions).