# converting a list of strings(csv) to a list of floats

Tags: python, string, floating-point

I am having some difficulty converting this list of strings into a list of floats. I tried this two ways and each returned different errors.

```
import csv
import math

unemp_reader = csv.reader(open('unemp.csv', 'rU'))
unemp_lines = list(unemp_reader)

for rows in unemp_lines:     #tried this way, but error tells me indices must be integers 
    i = 1
    for i in rows:
        a = map(float, unemp_lines[i])
        float_list.append(a)
    print float_list

for row in unemp_lines:  #tried this way but the list returned is empty
    y = row[1].split(",")[1:-1]
    float_list = [float(i) for i in y if i]
print float_list
```

Comment: What is your question? A little bit of prose would be good. Example input would be very useful too. There atre also issues. In the first example `float_list` is undefined. In the second, `C` is. Please try running your example code first.

Comment: It's worth noting that you should try to use
[the `with` statement](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example)
when opening files in Python. This is both more readable and removes the
possibility of a file being left unclosed (even when exceptions occur).

Comment: hey thanks for the quick responses, the inputs are

Comment: Year  Jan  Feb  Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec Annual

Comment: and number inputs under those column headers, what im trying to do is to take the numbers from the months (leaving out the annual and year) and use those floats to do calculations in python.

Comment: related: [convert a file into 2D float list](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11052673/4279)

Comment: Please improve your question by editing it, not by adding new information in comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue here in your first example is that a `for` loop doesn't give indices, it gives the values from the list. This means that your example doesn't really make any sense at all.

The second example takes the second item in the row, splits it on commas (which should all be dealt with by the `csv` module anyway) and then takes the second through second to last item of the resulting list. As I imagine there were no commas in the value this will take `[1:-1]` of a list with one element, returning an empty list. I can't really understand the intent here. You also then only store the data from the last row (overwriting `float_list` each time). You appear to be second-guessing the `csv` module and making this a lot harder than it is.

You need to stop overcomplicating it:

```
with open('unemp.csv', 'rb') as data:
    rows = csv.reader(data)
    next(rows) #Skip the headers.
    floats = [[float(item) for number, item in enumerate(row) if item and (1 <= number <= 12)] for row in rows]

print(floats)
```

To explain, first we use the `with` statement to open the file in a readable and pythonic way (which ensures the file is closed properly, even on exceptions). We then make a `csv.reader` to get our data from the CSV file. We skip the headers by advancing the iterator by one, meaning we start on the second row. We then use a list comprehension to produce a new list from the iterator, containing another list comprehension generating the floats of the values if those values exist, and are not in the `Year` or `Annual` column. To do this we use the `enumerate()` builtin to get the number of the column we are in, then do a check to ensure it's not `0` (`Year`) or `13` (`Annual`).

As J.F.Sebastian points out in the comments, the best solution is to allow the `csv` module to handle dealing with the numbers for you, by adding the named argument `quoting` to the `csv.reader()` call with the value `csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`. E.g:

```
with open('unemp.csv', 'rb') as data:
    rows = csv.reader(data, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    next(rows) #Skip the headers.
    floats = [[item for number, item in enumerate(row) if item and (1 <= number <= 12)] for row in rows]

print(floats)
```

Comment: Thanks Latty, i think whats screwing me up here is the first row of the csv file are headers and im not quite sure how to bypass that row to convert the rest of the data into the floats

Comment: always use `'rb'` for csv in Python 2. You could use `csv.QOUTE_NONNUMERIC` to parse numbers automatically

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Updated to use `rb` as the file mode. I just took that direct from the question. As to using `csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`, [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC) seem to imply it's only used for writing.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Wow, selective reading there on my part, weird that the writer is linked but the reader isn't. I tested anyway and it does, of course, work (it seemed exceedingly odd it wouldn't), I will update.

Comment: @lattyware thanks so much this makes sense, i spend the last 4 hours banging my head trying to figure this out :P

Comment: @Jonathan You might want to read up on the basics before you continue - you seem to be missing some major things like the fact that Python deals with 0-based indices, how `for` loops work, etc... Knowing this stuff better will make everything a lot easier.

Comment: btw, `csv.DictReader()` can parse the header line and provide access to fields by name to avoid messing with indexes. Also (unrelated) file is an iterator; you could call `next(data)`.