# Python Reading Each String in a file

Tags: python, string, file, input, int

I have a text file:

```
1 0 1 0 1 0

1 0 1 0 1 0

1 0 1 0 1 0

1 0 1 0 1 0
```

I want to be able to retrieve each string and convert it to an integer data type but my piece of code results in `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

```
tile_map = open('background_tiles.txt','r');

    for line in tile_map:

        for string in line:

             self.type = int(string);
```

What is the correct way to retrieve the data and convert it successfully?

Comment: related: [Reading file string into an array (In a pythonic way)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11052673/4279)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing to remember when iterating through the file is that the newline character is included, and when you try to cast that using `int()`, you will receive the error you are referencing (because Python doesn't know how to convert it into an integer). Try using something like:

```
with open('background_tiles.txt', 'r') as f:
    contents = f.readlines()

for line in contents:
    for c in line.split():
        self.type = int(c)
```

The `with` is a context manager, and it is generally a more efficient way to deal with files as it handles things like closing for you automatically when it leaves the block. `readlines` will read the file into a list (each line represented as a list element), and `split()` splits on the space.

Answer (score 3):

Your line contains string like - `"1 0 1 0 1 0"`. You need to split your line on space: -

```
for string in line.split():
    self.type = int(string);
```