# Python . How to get rid of '\r' in string?

Tags: python, string, list, replace

I have an excel file that I converted to a text file with a list of numbers.

```
test = 'filelocation.txt'

in_file = open(test,'r')

for line in in_file:
    print line

1.026106236
1.660274766
2.686381002
4.346655769
7.033036771
1.137969254

a = []

for line in in_file:
    a.append(line)
print a

'1.026106236\r1.660274766\r2.686381002\r4.346655769\r7.033036771\r1.137969254'
```

I wanted to assign each value (in each line) to an individual element in the list.  Instead it is creating one element separated by \r . i'm not sure what \r is but why is putting these into the code ?

I think I know a way to get rid of the \r from the string but i want to fix the problem from the source

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To accepts any of `\r`, `\n`, `\r\n` as a newline you could use `'U'` (universal newline) file mode:

```
>>> open('test_newlines.txt', 'rb').read()
'a\rb\nc\r\nd'
>>> list(open('test_newlines.txt'))
['a\rb\n', 'c\r\n', 'd']
>>> list(open('test_newlines.txt', 'U'))
['a\n', 'b\n', 'c\n', 'd']
>>> open('test_newlines.txt').readlines()
['a\rb\n', 'c\r\n', 'd']
>>> open('test_newlines.txt', 'U').readlines()
['a\n', 'b\n', 'c\n', 'd']
>>> open('test_newlines.txt').read().split()
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

If you want to get a numeric (float) array from the file; see [Reading file string into an array (In a pythonic way)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11052673/4279)

Answer (score 2):

use `rstrip()` or `rstrip('\r')` if you're sure than the last character is always `\r`.

```
for line in in_file:
    print line.rstrip()
```

help on `str.rstrip()`:

```
S.rstrip([chars]) -> string or unicode

Return a copy of the string S with trailing whitespace removed.
If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.
If chars is unicode, S will be converted to unicode before stripping
```

`str.strip()` removes both trailing and leading whitespaces.

Comment: note: `.rstrip()` won't help because `for line in in_file` doesn't recognize `\r` as a newline on the OPs machine so `line` may contain multiple `\r` inside,  try: `'1\r2\r'.rstrip()`

Answer (score 0):

You can strip the carriage returns and newlines from the line by using strip()

```
line.strip()
```

i.e.

```
for line in in_file:
    a.append(line.strip())
print a
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this do:

```
for line in in_file:
    a.append(line.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

`.strip()` the lines to remove the whitespace that you don't need:

```
lines = []

with open('filelocation.txt', 'r') as handle:
    for line in handle:
        line = line.strip()
        lines.append(line)

        print line

print lines
```

Also, I'd advise that you use the `with ...` notation to open a file. It's cleaner and closes the file automatically.

Answer (score 0):

First, I generally like @J.F. Sebastian's answer, but my use case is closer to [Python 2.7.1: How to Open, Edit and Close a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471049/python-2-7-1-how-to-open-edit-and-close-a-csv-file), since my string came from a *text* file was output from Excel as a csv and was furthermore input using the csv module.  As indicated at that question:

> as for the 'rU' vs 'rb' vs ..., csv files really should be binary so
>   use 'rb'. However, its not uncommon to have csv files from someone who
>   copied it into notepad on windows and later it was joined with some
>   other file so you have funky line endings. How you deal with that
>   depends on your file and your preference.  –  @kalhartt Jan 23 at 3:57

I'm going to stick with reading as 'rb' as recommended in [the python docs](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.python.org%2Flibrary%2Fcsv.html&ei=Orq9Uo_QCYXboAThkYHoCA&usg=AFQjCNH1TvboyrkQiNKru1Z1o0-RkeoVRw&bvm=bv.58187178,d.cGU&cad=rja).  For now, I know that the \r inside a cell is a result of quirks of how I'm using Excel, so I'll just create a global option for replacing '\r' with something else, which for now will be '\n', but later could be '' (an empty string, not a double quote) with a simple json change.