# How to add columns from different csv files into my existing file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two files one with 50,000 rows and 12 features in it. Another csv file which has 670 approx rows and 2 features. I would like to merge the columns from two different files into a single file.

Please help me with this, how to solve this problem. Make sure to give your answer in Python only.

Answer (score 0):

What do you exactly mean by merging, as it seems the number of lines / features isn't the same?

I would load the smallest file in python, and then read line by line the first one to inject/update content.

You can [have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471049/python-2-7-1-how-to-open-edit-and-close-a-csv-file#14471485) if you want to know hos to manipulate a csv file in Python.